# Given Data Frame containing string values, how to find the correlation between a group of values in a pandas dataframe column?

Tags: python, dataframe, correlation

I have a dataframe df:

```
ID            District     Var1 (Average Down Time)      Var2 (Incident Count)
0206571-017   TSUEN WAN    1.2                                4
0206571-017   TSUEN WAN    2.1                                6
0206571-017   TSUEN WAN    3.0                                7
0206571-017   TSUEN WAN    1.3                                8
0206571-019   TSING YI     2.1                                9
0206571-018   CENTRAL      3.2                                13
```

As a data analyst,

1. I want to find the correlation coefficient value between `Var1` and `Var2` for every `ID`
2. I would like to find which district contains highest Average Down Time / Incident Count as separate CSV

Given data columns containing string value e.g. ID / District, please provide metre way to encode or group st that I can conduct df.corr() to output correlation matrix

Answer (score 1):

In order to answer your question on finding the correlation coefficient between var1 and var2 for every ID, this provides a way on how it can be coded,

```
corr_coeff = df.groupby('ID')[['Var1', 'Var2']].corr()
print(corr_coeff)
```

Result,

```
                    Var1     Var2
ID                                
0206571-017 Var1  1.00000  0.30327
            Var2  0.30327  1.00000
0206571-018 Var1      NaN      NaN
            Var2      NaN      NaN
0206571-019 Var1      NaN      NaN
            Var2      NaN      NaN
```

And for the second question on find which district contains highest Average Down Time / Incident Count as separate CSV,

```
avg_district = df.groupby('District')[['Var1', 'Var2']].mean()
highest_avg_downtime = avg_district['Var1'].idxmax()
highest_avg_incidents = avg_district['Var2'].idxmax()
highest_avg_downtime_df = df[df['District'] == highest_avg_downtime]
highest_avg_incidents_df = df[df['District'] == highest_avg_incidents]
highest_avg_downtime_df.to_csv('highest_avg_downtime.csv', index=False)
highest_avg_incidents_df.to_csv('highest_avg_incidents.csv', index=False)
```

The Highest Average Down Time / Incident Count will be will be provided in two different CSV files named "**highest_avg_downtime.csv**" and "**highest_avg_incidents.csv**".

In order to encode a categorical value(i.e., String) to a numerical value, we can use label encoder,

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le = LabelEncoder()
df['ID'] = le.fit_transform(df['ID'])
df['District'] = le.fit_transform(df['District'])
```

And this will provide a result like this,

```
   ID   District    Var1    Var2
0   0   2           1.2     4
1   0   2           2.1     6
2   0   2           3.0     7
3   0   2           1.3     8
4   2   1           2.1     9
5   1   0           3.2     13
```

After encoding if `df.corr()` is applied to find the output correlation matrix, it would result as,

```
          ID          District     Var1         Var2
ID        1.000000    -0.714286    0.273190     0.585800
District  -0.714286   1.000000     -0.589516    -0.898227
Var1      0.273190    -0.589516    1.000000     0.648563
Var2      0.585800    -0.898227    0.648563     1.000000
```